# understanding a signal from its mathematical formula

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, signal-analysis

[image]

I can understand from unit step function in the end of the equation that $n=[3 \quad4]$, but I cannot understand how delta function affects the signal in order to solve it and put it on matlab.

Answer:
[image]

Comment: what do you mean with "solve it"? There's nothing to be solved here; it's an equation that gives you $x_1$.

Comment: I cannot understand how this equation can be written in matlab, that's what I mean by "solve it".

Comment: You cannot directly write it in Matlab, because of the infinite sums. However, you can plot the resulting signal in Matlab, guessing the values of $x_1$ for all $n$s

Comment: @LaurentDuval I know I cannot write it directly, I just couldn't think how I could do it. Βasically, how to make it to a form that can be written in matlab. Your answer made it very clear to me though. :)

Comment: Good, please append you final solution when you get it

Comment: I may be wrong (late on Sunday), but the value at $n=1$ bothers me

Comment: There are two problems with the plot for the equation: 1. there should be no impulse at $n=1$ (as mentioned by Laurent), and 2., the two values at $n=3$ and $n=4$ should be negative.

Comment: I updated the plot, please check on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is misleading is that you ought to find the values of $x_1[n]$ for all $n$.

For the first term, assuming convention $\cdot^0=1$, you get $\delta[n]+\delta[n-2]$. For the second one, all terms except for $k=2$ cancel each other, so you only gain another $\delta[n-2]$. Then, as you guessed, the last term (without the initial minus sign), is 1 for $n=3,4$, and zero elsewhere.

Comment: I think the matlab code for this is the following:
clear,clc
n=-10:10;
x=zeros(1,length(n));
x(11:12)=1;
x(13)=2;
x(14:15)=1;
stem(n,x)

Comment: I'd suggest you happen it with a plot to your question, at the end.